# 7zip reports corrupt file although checksum matches

Tags: archiving, 7-zip

I transferred a large (140GB) disk image to my machine over ftp in 7z format using 4Gb chunks. When I had downloaded it, none of the chunks can be opened using 7zip. On the first file, I get an "Unspecified error", on the remaining files, I get "cannot open .. as an archive". No 7zip operations such as Test/Extract/Open works, on any of the files. Naturally I suspect corruptions, but it seems odd if every single file had been corrupted in transit.

On the machine where the files were downloaded from they open just fine in the same version of 7zip as I'm using on the receiving end. When I do a checksum on the 7z.001 file it is identical on both the sending and receiving machines. A corruption in a *later* file in the sequence shouldn't affect how the 7z.001 file is opened, right?

What could be the issue? The .7z.001 file shouldn't be corrupt as the checksum is matching, but still all decompressors seem to agree that this file is indeed corrupt. What shold I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem, will answer my own question in case anyone stumbles across the same issue: Opening, Extracting or Testing the first file requires ALL FILES to be present and uncorrupted. Not just the one you are trying to open.

Corrupted or missing files *later in the sequence will mean that the first archive fails to open with a cryptic error message*. This is of course an unbelievable flaw in their file format, as well as horrible UX to not report a proper error message informing about a missing file.

Comment: Considering 7zip hasn't been updated in years its hard to fault the current UI for being bad.